# Компактный Word2Vec

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, word2vec

Есть ли какие-нибудь w2v модели, которые не требуют наличия словаря. Так, всё то, что я нашёл в torchtext хочет сначала узнать словарь [build_vocab](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vocab.html#glove). Но если у меня огромный корпус текста, я бы хотел иметь модель, которая работает на уровне словосочетаний. Но я не нашёл такой.

Comment: Что-то я не могу себе представить как можно использовать `Word2vec` без словаря? Либо вы используете готовые `embeddings` (такие как `Glove`) либо считаете их сами. Даже при огромном корпусе число уникальных слов редко превышает 20-50K слов.

Comment: `я бы хотел иметь модель, которая работает на уровне словосочетаний` - вы рассматривали обычные `n-grams`?

Comment: @MaxU Типо того, для них построить ngrams2v, а на их основе -- Glove или подобное. А в чём проблема?

Comment: Идея интересная, но мне кажется это будет занимать слишком много места, чтобы поместиться в памяти. Можете попробовать взять исходник `Glove` и обучить на своем корпусе (предварительно получив `bi-grams`)...  А что у вас за задача? `Doc2Vec` - вам не подойдет?

Comment: Задача, конечно, решается словарём. Ничего особенного toxicChallage, если знаете. Doc2Vec как построить (есть ли готовые)? Играюсь с pyTorch и возникла такая идея. Возникла она из простых соображений, что данные не помещаются в память

Comment: [вот пример](https://medium.com/@klintcho/doc2vec-tutorial-using-gensim-ab3ac03d3a1). Готовые не существуют по определению документа. Это как заранее написать все возможные музыкальные произведения, которые можно написать, используя семь нот. С документами еще сложнее - слов гораздо больше... ;)

Comment: @MaxU, ну, да, логично. Мне даже за вопрос стыдно стало. Конечно, его не существует